# how to get started with a retinal scan project?

Tags: image-processing, biometrics

hello
I have to develop a software for my college course that will perform retinal scan, i.e, if a picture is provided the location of the retina will be detected by the program.
But i have got no clue on how to implement this project. Can anyone please provide any relevant information?

Comment: Looks like you have a misconception about how retinal scan works. Please, read http://www.discoveriesinmedicine.com/Ra-Thy/Retinography.html - Don't confuse it with iris recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps start out researching how a face detection algorithm is implemented, and then implement that same algorithm with an iris as the target.

Heres an open source Java implementation of a face detection algorithm: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/)

Answer (score 0):

What is the college course? Hopefully you're given more guidance (or should already have knowledge in the area) beyond "develop an algorithm to find the retina/iris". It could probably be done with shape recognition, or various other techniques depending on what the image is like. Are we talking about "Here's a closeup of a face, find the eyes", or "Here's a picture of 10 people, find the eyes"? The algorithms will be very different in those two cases.